# Hidden Markov process

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I've been reading about hidden Markov models, and I'm interested in both discrete and continuous time models (and discrete states). I have found many papers on the discrete time HMM, but not the continuous time HMM. I really want to know how to to set up the model and estimate the parameters.

Does anyone know a good reference?

Answer (score 5):

The rabiner tutorial on HMMs is a must, first section covers discrete state space HMMs heavily, but he gets into continuous state space HMMs around page 10 or something:

[Rabiner Tutorial](http://people.sabanciuniv.edu/berrin/cs512/reading/rabiner-tutorial-on-hmm.pdf)